# How to use pseudo hash in modern perl?

Tags: perl, hash

I have data loaded in next format (probably loaded from `.csv` file):

```
my $data =  [
   [ 'id', 'name', 'value' ],
   [   23,  'foo',      77 ],
   [   44,  'bar',   'dfd' ],
]
```

I want to access data like:

```
$data->[$n]{ name }
```

I know that in old perl I could use [phash](https://perldoc.pl/perlref.html#Pseudo-hashes%3a-Using-an-array-as-a-hash) (pseudo hash), but it was deprecated and replaced by [`fields`](https://perldoc.pl/fields.html) pragma.

As far as I can see that is used for objects. In my case I do not create objects and do not use classes.

How should I use `fields` in my use case? Please provide an example

Comment: Interesting, here is some more [information](http://perl.mines-albi.fr/perl5.8.5/5.8.5/pod/perlref.html#pseudohashes__using_an_array_as_a_hash) about the original usage of psuedo-hashes perl v5.8.

Comment: Wiow, that hails way back ... so far back that a title may be a little misleading

Comment: @zdim: By doing `$data->[$n]{name}` I want to get value of `name` field. Updated question a bit.

Answer (score 6):

Using the [Text::CSV_XS](https://metacpan.org/pod/Text::CSV_XS) module to read your  CSV data, and telling it what the column names are based on the first line:

```
#!/usr/bin/env perl
use strict;
use warnings;
use feature 'say';
use Text::CSV_XS;

my $csv = Text::CSV_XS->new({binary => 1, auto_diag => 1});
$csv->column_names($csv->getline(\*DATA));
my $data = $csv->getline_hr_all(\*DATA);
say $data->[0]->{'name'}; # prints foo

__DATA__
id,name,value
23,foo,77
44,bar,dfd
```

Consider looping over the records instead of reading the entire file at once, though. See the documentation for [`getline_hr`](https://metacpan.org/pod/Text::CSV_XS#getline_hr) for a couple of ways to do it.

Comment: Hi. I can not use Text::CSV_XS.  I already have data loaded in such format. Also I clarify question a bit: I am not sure that data is loaded from `.csv`

Comment: @Eugen Konkov, Then use Text::CSV

Comment: @ikegami: I read `Text::CSV` more carefully and now I am confused. [details](https://github.com/makamaka/Text-CSV/issues/45)

Answer (score 4):

If you can [use Text::CSV_XS as Shawn shows](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60760472/2766176), do that.

We have an exercise in [Intermediate Perl](https://www.intermediateperl.com) that does this. Use the first row to map the header names to position, then use that hash to translate the other way. Here it is with heavy use of [postfix dereferencing](https://www.effectiveperlprogramming.com/2014/09/use-postfix-dereferencing/):

```
use v5.24;

my $data =  [
   [ 'id', 'name', 'value' ],
   [   23,  'foo',      77 ],
   [   44,  'bar',   'dfd' ],
];

# ikegami's suggestion
my %name_to_index = map { $data->[0][$i] => $_ } 0..$data->[0]->$#*;

foreach my $i ( 1 .. $data->$#* ) {
    say $data->[$i][ $name_to_index{name} ]
    }
```

Here's the circumfix version that works with versions before v5.24, but I think it's uglier (and you have to use a six year old, unsupported Perl):

```
use v5.10;

my $data =  [
   [ 'id', 'name', 'value' ],
   [   23,  'foo',      77 ],
   [   44,  'bar',   'dfd' ],
];

# ikegami's suggestion
my %name_to_index = map { $data->[0][$i] => $_ } 0.. $#{ $data->[0] };

foreach my $i ( 1 .. $#{ $data } ) {
    say $data->[$i][ $name_to_index{name} ]
    }
```

Since the real code is probably much more complex, I think it's often easier to understand when you don't drill down into the data structure everywhere. If you don't mind the extra work (as you would in a hot loop), you can make your row into a hash where the keys are the headers (similar to what `Text::CSV_XS` does) then play with that hash without thinking about the entire chain of dereferences. This example uses a hash slice to populate everything at once. After that you play with `%hash` instead of `$data->[$i][...]`:

```
use v5.24;

my $data =  [
   [ 'id', 'name', 'value' ],
   [   23,  'foo',      77 ],
   [   44,  'bar',   'dfd' ],
];

my @headers = $data->[0]->@*;
foreach my $i ( 1 .. $data->$#* ) {
    my %hash;
    @hash{ @headers } = $data->[$i]->@*;

    say $hash{name};
    }
```

Curiously, right after the [Pseudohash section in perlref](https://perldoc.perl.org/perlref.html#Pseudo-hashes%3a-Using-an-array-as-a-hash), the docs show an example with function templates. Instead of the hash to do the mapping, you can define subroutines. Some people like that the name of the header index looks a little cleaner, but I don't think this is worth the extra explanation of the soft `refs` violation and the explanation of type globs:

```
use v5.24;

my $data =  [
   [ 'id', 'name', 'value' ],
   [   23,  'foo',      77 ],
   [   44,  'bar',   'dfd' ],
];

foreach my $name ( $data->[0]->@* ) {
    state $n = 0;
    my $m = $n++;      # don't reference $n
    no strict 'refs';  # Hey there!
    *{uc $name} = sub () { $m }; # runtime sub definition
    }

foreach my $i ( 1 .. $data->$#* ) {
    say $data->[$i][ NAME() ]
    }
```

Comment: @Polar Bear, The OP specifically want an alternative to something found in older versions of Perl because they don't have an older version of Perl. /// What concerns me is the fact that the code can't be used in a sub (because of the use of `state`.) Fixed: `my $names = $data->[0]; my %name_to_index = map { $names->[0] => $_ } 0..$#$names;`

Comment: @Polar Bear, Off-topic. The OP isn't asking if they should move to a newer version of Perl or not, and this answer doesn't touch that topic either. Please keep comments on-topic.

Comment: @ikegami -- OP asked how to achieve desired access method with mentioning that old 'phash' is deprecated. He was not specific about perl version as you have stated. I only added that this solution is not applicable on old systems which can not upgrade perl due _valid reason_. My answer is for all systems including very old.

Comment: @ikegami - yeah, I get overly excited with `state` in `map`. I added your version. Thanks.  For everyone else: when I use state, that variable's value lives forever. If I wanted to do this for multiple data structures, that map could not start at `$n = 0` again. For a small example I accidentally get away with it and I shouldn't optimize for that.

Answer (score 0):

The `$data` require some conversion into array of hashes.

First row of `$data` is a fields name, it will be used as hash keys.

Next we need:

> *walk* through other rows of array
>
> - create hash from keys and data
> - push hash into new array
>
> when all data processed
>
> return `$new` reference to *final* array

At this point elements of `$new` array reference can be accessed as `$new->[0]{id}`.

Please see the following code demonstrating how desired data storage can be achieved.

*NOTE:* this code does not rely on new perl *features* and should produce desired result on systems even 20 years old (where perl update impossible for valid reason).

Last `for` loop demonstrates printing all elements of `$new` array reference.

```
use strict;
use warnings;
use feature 'say';

use Data::Dumper;

my $debug = 0;                             # debug = 1 - Debug mode ON

my $data =  [
   [ 'id', 'name', 'value' ],
   [   23,  'foo',      77 ],
   [   44,  'bar',   'dfd' ],
];

my $new = convert($data);

say Dumper($new) if $debug;

for ( 0..$#{$new} ) {                      # walk through result array
    say '-' x 35;
    say 'Id:    ' . $new->[$_]{id};
    say 'Name:  ' . $new->[$_]{name};
    say 'Value: ' . $new->[$_]{value};
    say '-' x 35;
}

sub convert {
    my $data = shift;
    
    my @fields = @{$data->[0]};            # used as hash key
    
    my @data;

    for ( 1..$#{$data} ) {                # walk through $data starting from index=1
        my %hash;
        @hash{@fields} = @{$data->[$_]};  # store data in hash
        push @data, \%hash;               # store hash into array
    }
    
    return \@data;                        # return reference to array of hashes
}
```

Output

```
-----------------------------------
Id:    23
Name:  foo
Value: 77
-----------------------------------
-----------------------------------
Id:    44
Name:  bar
Value: dfd
-----------------------------------
```